# I have a JSON object in a file that I stored in a variable, but I can't seem to do anything I want with it because it is nested inside of an array

Tags: php, json, csv

My json file has contents formatted like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "keyword_filter": null,
    "name": "My Name ",
    "type": "some product",
    "sku": "1234567",
    "nested_obj": {
      "url": "http://someurl.com",
      "resource": "/orders"
    }
  }
]
```

I can read it into a variable like this:

```
$json_string = file_get_contents($jsonFile);
```

Ultimately, I need to create a tab-delimited file out of it, but I can't even seem to iterate over it.  Here's what I've tried:

```
foreach($json_string as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

This gives me an error saying I've supplied an invalid argument in my foreach loop.

I tried reading it into an array like this:

```
$json_array = file($jsonFile);
foreach($json_array as $item) {
    echo $item;
}
```

This echoes an array that has 1 item, which is the JSON object.

Can someone please tell me how to get into that JSON object so I can iterate over it?
Encoding it back into JSON just doubly escapes quotes and decoding it returns NULL.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated... and any hints on converting to tab-delimited file would be super extraordinarily appreciated, but I'll be fine with just the first step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this :

```
<?php

$str = '[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "keyword_filter": null,
    "name": "My Name ",
    "type": "some product",
    "sku": "1234567",
    "nested_obj": {
      "url": "http://someurl.com",
      "resource": "/orders"
    }
  }
]';


$array  = json_decode($str, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);

/// write the forech basd on the array out put.    

foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item['id'];
}

?>
```

I got the output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [keyword_filter] => 
            [name] => My Name 
            [type] => some product
            [sku] => 1234567
            [nested_obj] => Array
                (
                    [url] => http://someurl.com
                    [resource] => /orders
                )

        )

)
1
```

And that is your desired out put. Here at the end of the array you can see `1` that is the value of `echo $item['id'];`

Comment: Ok... I got it..., I was making a pretty dumb mistake. I was querying the file on a remote server instead of my local version... although it seems like it should have worked anyway.  But regardless, this works now, and I feel really silly for thinking it was a huge issue.  Thanks for your help sir!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

json_decode : converts the json string to array : http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$array  = json_decode($json_string, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);

/// write the forech basd on the array out put.    

foreach($array as $item) {
    echo $item['id'];
}
```

Comment: when I try this, I get:  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: what is the out put of `echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);`

Comment: `print_r($array)` doesn't output anything, `var_dump($array)` outputs null

Comment: check in your phpinfo, if json is enabled.

Comment: yes it is enabled... just checked.  i think i'm running into a problem because the entire object is wrapped in brackets, so when I decode it, it already thinks it is an array... does that make sense?

Comment: ohhhhh... there is a small issue in the code it is `true` not `ture`..I am sorry for that.

Comment: edited the line : `$array  = json_decode($json_string, true);`

Comment: that's ok... I already caught that error.  I have already tried that method.  The problem is not getting an array, because I have the array.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to create a tab-delimited file out of it**

```
$json_string = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonFile), true);

foreach ($json_string as $k => $vals){
 // tab delimited header
 if ($k == 0) {
  echo join ("\t", array_keys($vals))."\n";
 }
 // tab delimited row
 echo join ("\t", $vals)."\n";

}
```

Comment: and you are my second hero!  i get an array to string conversion error, i'm guessing because there are null values in my json file... but that's something i can work with.  thanks for your help with this second piece of the puzzle.

Comment: i want to mark this as solved, but i can only mark one thing as solved, but either way, i'm considering this thing solved, fyi